# My scrollview does not scroll (tried all the answers from stackoverflow)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I wanted all the elements to scroll, i did not give any values so that it may work on other devices too which are not of the similar size of mine, i tried nearly all the answers and suggestions given over here and failed to see it scroll, i came here as this is my last resort.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".arabicnamazfour">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="25">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="رکوع کی دعا"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                android:backgroundTint="#32728F"
                android:backgroundTintMode="src_over" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="سُبْحَانَ رَبِّيَ الْعَظِیْمِ ۔   (مسلم)        کم از کم تین مرتبہ" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="یا دعا پڑھے۔ "
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="سُبْحَانَکَ اَللّٰہُمَّ رَبَّنَا وَبِحَمْدِکَ اَللّٰہُمَّ اغْفِرْلِیْ ۔              (بخاری و مسلم)" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView25"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="رکوع کے بعد کی دعا"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="رَبَّنَاوَ لَکَ الْحَمْدُ ۔" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView28"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="یا یہ کہے۔"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView29"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="رَبَّنَا وَ لَکَ الْحَمْدُ‘ حَمْدًاکَثِیْرًا طَیِّبًا مُّبَارَکًا فِیْہ ۔    (بخاری)" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fourth" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fifth" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sixth" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/seventh" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:backgroundTint="#32728F"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="4"

                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_before_24" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried all the answers and everything that i could think of, but it simply wouldnt scroll

Comment: Your layout scrolls if the height exceeds the available screen height. It won't scroll if all elements fit.

Comment: All the elements do not fit on the screen, I tried running it on my phone and I can see in the design section that all the elements are not on the layout they extend beyond that. @Cheticamp